# Using fork to create a folder and file

Tags: c, linux

Using `fork()`, I want the child to create a folder with the argument that I gave from console:

> ./example abc

and the parent will put a `file.txt` inside this folder with all current processes.

My problem is that the parent doesn't recognize this folder.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int fid,status;
    fid=fork();
    if(fid==0)
    {
        mkdir(argv[1],0777);
        wait(&status);
    }
    else if(fid>0)
    {
        system("ps -A >> argv[1]/file.txt");
    }
    else
        printf("fork failed");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String to system() API is wrong in a sense that argv[1] will not be replaced by it's value. E.g. you entered 

./example dexter 

but the string which is passed to system API is this

"ps -A >> argv[1]/file.txt"

Comment: Why do you need to use `fork`? You could achieve this much more simply without using `fork` at all; it's not clear what you gain by forking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int fid,status;

    char string[50];
    sprintf(string, "ps -A >> %s/file.txt", argv[1]);

    fid=fork();
    if(fid==0)
    {
        mkdir(argv[1],0777);
        wait(&status);
    }
    else if(fid>0)
    {
        system(string);
    }
    else
        printf("fork failed");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solved, thank you ,one of my mistakes was the wait(&status) in child as well.

Comment: Too bad if someone passes a long filename to your program, though... a better solution would calculate the right buffer size and allocate it dynamically, rather than using a fixed-size array.